# Compare two arrays and return an array of integers which values are result of comparison

Tags: c#, arrays

[My not woring version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaJSB.png)Write a method which takes two integer arrays of the same length. Method should return an array of integers which values are result of comparison of input arrays using the following rules:

```
a[i] > b[i], then 1
a[i] == b[i], then 0
a[i] < b[i], then -1
```

Possible method signature:

```
static int[] CompareArrays(int[] a, int[] b) { ... }
```

Sample input:

```
a = [1, 3, 9]

b = [-2, 6, 9]
```

Expected output:

```
[1, -1, 0]
```

Use for loop to iterate both input arrays and assign values to output arrays.

Comment: sounds like homework, please add code and describe where you are having problems

Comment: You've only listed requirements which unfortunately is not enough to get help. you must have tried to accomplish the task at hand before asking for help. voting to close as it's "too broad" in the current state.

Comment: Try `Zip` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Zip or a simple for loop should be enough to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like homework but following should get you started...

```
static int[] CompareArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
  //add checks to make sure a.Length == b.Length;

  //allocate space for output array
  int[] retVal = new int[a.Length];

  //iterate through all the items in the input arrays... checking length of any one of the input arrays is just fine since we assume both should be same length
  for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i) {
    retVal[i] = 0;

    //add your rules here e.g. a[i] > b[i] then 1 etc
    if(a[i] > b[i]) {
      retVal[i] = 1;
    }
  }

  return retVal;
}
```